# console.log vs. return; two different values

Tags: node.js, http

I'm somewhat confused here. I have a function which when I'm using `return` i'm receiving an `undefined` but if I use `console.log()`, I get `200`...

Here's my code so far:

```
var getStatus = function(subreddit){
    var options = {
        host: "http://www.reddit.com",
        port: 80,
        path: "/r/" + subreddit
    }
    http.get(options, function(res){
        console.log(res.statusCode); // Returns 200
        return res.statusCode; // Returns undefined
    })
}

console.log(getStatus("HIMYM"));
```

Comment: how do you get the return value ?

Comment: @samitha Sorry, added it now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With async calls you need to use callback to get the value, return inside http.get()'s callback won't do it.  Here is the code using callback in the caller:

```
var getStatus = function(subreddit, callback){
    var options = {
        host: "http://www.reddit.com",
        port: 80,
        path: "/r/" + subreddit
    }
    http.get(options, function(res){
        console.log(res.statusCode); // Returns 200
        callback( res.statusCode); // Returns to caller's callback
    });
}
getStatus("HIMYM", function(statusCode) {
    console.log(statusCode);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `function(res)` returns the status back to `http.get()` but `function(subreddit)` doesn't return anything, thus you get `undefined` back.

Unless `http.get()` is an async function, the following should work:

```
var getStatus = function(subreddit){
    var options = {
        host: "http://www.reddit.com",
        port: 80,
        path: "/r/" + subreddit
    };
    var result;
    http.get(options, function(res){
        console.log(res.statusCode); // Returns 200
        result = res.statusCode; // Returns undefined
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Oh, you're right! Thanks! (I feel quite stupid now :D)

Comment: jQuery.get() takes the param `async: false` if you need it. Does that work for you?

Comment: Nop, doesn't seem to work D: The async's series module won't do it either.

Comment: Another common pattern is to simply move the code after the get request to a function that you call from the `http.get()` callback instead of returning data. That has the benefit of not locking javascript while data is retrieved.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51936/discussion-between-mobilpadde-and-mattias-aslund)